# How many combinations can you find?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I got a interesting question from my boss today.

Imagine you have:

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9

and beneath these numbers I have to place 10 numbers and if I place number 6 beneath 0 I must have six zeros placed out. Let me give an example for one combination that I have found.

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9

6   2   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0

I have six zeros and two ones and a number two.

I'm wondering if there is some way to find all combinations that satisfy these conditions. What I believe I have found is that:

A = [0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]

I = [1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]

X = [x0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9]

X*A'= X*I'= 10

Any help would be appreciated as, evidently, my bonus depends on a solution :S.

Answer (score 3):

You must have zeros under at least four of $5,6,7,8,9$, (otherwise the sum exceeds $10$) so the number under $0$ is at least $4$.  Now the total of all the numbers below something besides zero is at most six, so you must have zeros below at least six of $3,4,5,6,7,8,9$.  That means the number under zero is at least six.  If there are six zeros, the other four must come from $2+1+1$ and that is the solution you have.  If there are seven zeros, the other three must come from $2+1$, but you don't have two of anything.  $8$ and $9$ zeros fail similarly.  You have the only solution.

Comment: That's a very neat reasoning. I wonder if it can be generalised to other sizes. For example, all sizes up to  $[0\, 1\, 2]$ don't have solutions at all.

Comment: Your solution can be generalized.  Given the range $[0,n]$ you would have $n-3\ 0$'s, $2\ 1$'s, $1\ 2$ and $1\ n-3$.  This works for $n \gt 5$  I think this logic can show there are no more, but haven't checked it.  For $[0,3]$ there is $2020$ as a special case.